# JavaFX: FXML script to disable button if another object is active

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, fxml

i am using JavaFX with jdk 1.8.

It is possible to disable a button when another button is disabled, using a script on the FXML file?

Comment: Java isn't JavaScript.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [expression binding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#expression_binding) in the fxml.

Assuming you want to bind the `Button.disable` property of one button to the `Button.disabled` property of another button here:

```xml
<CheckBox fx:id="cb" text="button 1 disabled"/>
<Button fx:id="b1" text="button 1" disable="${cb.selected}"/> <!-- disable button iff the checkbox is checked -->
<Button text="button 2" disable="${b1.disabled}"/> <!-- disable this button iff b1 is disabled -->
```

If the `b1` needs to be added to the scene at a later point, you need to use `<fx:define>` before `b2` to create the button and use `<fx:reference>` to add it to the scene at a later point.

```xml
<fx:define>
     <Button fx:id="b1" text="button 1" disable="${cb.selected}"/>
</fx:define>
<Button text="button 2" disable="${b1.disabled}"/>
<fx:reference source="b1" />
```